# IDEA cannot resolve symbol "println"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Suddenly IntelliJ IDEA is complaining about everything - I cannot even type "sout" to get   `System.out.println();` out. If I type it manually, it will have "println" in read and say "cannot resolve symbol println". What's up with that?

I've tried:

- Invalidate/restart cache
- Update JDK(1.8.44), re-try to set it again(it's the right path, no complaints there?)

What else can one do?

Comment: Make sure the file you are editing is in a folder marked as `sources` / `tests`

Comment: this is in `src/main/java` - been working fine up until now,..

Comment: Is indexing complete?

Comment: Yes this is after indexing.

Comment: Go to project structure and make sure that your sdk is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like there is something wrong with your JDK setting. The easiest way is to re-create it:

Under Project Structure > Project Settings > Project > Project SDK:

Click 'New...' + JDK. Select the path where the JDK is located.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this by including main() method.

```
public class MyFirstProject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world");
    }
}
```